# TCPDF strange behaviour with SVG image

Tags: svg, tcpdf

I'm facing a strange behaviour of TCPDF rendering when I try to generate a PDF from a PHP code.

Here is my SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg x="0pt" y="0pt" width="1020pt" height="1020pt" viewBox="0 0 1020 1020" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="1">
    <title>LAC ET FORET</title>
  </g>
  <g id="2">
    <title>VILLE</title>
    <g id="3">
      <title>Velo</title>
      <defs>
        <title>Path</title>
        <g id="4">
          <defs>
            <path id="5" d="M7.5,259.922 C213.226,259.922,380,427.885,380,635.077 C380,842.27,213.226,1010.23,7.5,1010.23 C-198.226,1010.23,-365,842.27,-365,635.077 C-365,427.885,-198.226,259.922,7.5,259.922 z"/>
          </defs>
          <use xlink:href="#5" style="fill:none;opacity:1;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:20;"/>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#4"/>
      <defs>
        <title>Path Copy</title>
        <g id="6">
          <defs>
            <path id="7" d="M1012.5,259.922 C1218.23,259.922,1385,427.825,1385,634.944 C1385,842.063,1218.23,1009.97,1012.5,1009.97 C806.774,1009.97,640,842.063,640,634.944 C640,427.825,806.774,259.922,1012.5,259.922 z"/>
          </defs>
          <use xlink:href="#7" style="fill:none;opacity:1;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:20;"/>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#6"/>
      <defs>
        <title>Path</title>
        <g id="8">
          <defs>
            <path id="9" d="M1010.1,635.507 C1010.1,635.507,760.013,134.872,760.013,134.872 C760.013,134.872,9.90756,134.892,9.90756,134.892 C9.90756,134.892,10.0611,635.784,10.0611,635.784 C10.0611,635.784,759.988,134.636,759.988,134.636 C759.988,134.636,760.03,10.1281,760.03,10.1281 C760.03,10.1281,766.014,9.93965,885.136,9.93963 C965.555,9.93962,970.933,135.054,885.062,135.054"/>
          </defs>
          <use xlink:href="#9" style="fill:none;opacity:1;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:20;"/>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#8"/>
      <defs>
        <title>Path</title>
        <g id="10">
          <defs>
            <path id="11" d="M1060.52,636.085 C1060.52,636.085,1009.94,636.085,1009.94,636.085"/>
          </defs>
          <use xlink:href="#11" style="fill:none;opacity:1;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:20;"/>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#10"/>
      <defs>
        <title>Path</title>
        <g id="12">
          <defs>
            <path id="13" d="M-30.5769,135.081 C-30.5769,135.081,10.1142,135.081,10.1142,135.081"/>
          </defs>
          <use xlink:href="#13" style="fill:none;opacity:1;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:20;"/>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#12"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And here is my PHP code for PDF generation: It's include in a loop that put images side by side.

```
$pdf->ImageSVG($file = '@' . $img, $line*($iconsize*$ratioOf), $column*($iconsize*$ratioOf), $iconsize, $iconsize, $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);
```

I don't know why but rendering looks something like this: I mean the image is not display correctly. The first one is OK. Then the second one is size reduce.

If I use the same SVG file but only with `<PATH>` (no more use) including the style. It works fine. Something in My SVG would have TCPDF running strangly. I cannot figure it out.

[image: myPDF with issue screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I know its a little late but maybe one day someone needs the answer.
The tcpdf cant handle use-elements so you need to replace them with the content they point on, like this:

```php
$imagePath = "folder/imagename.svg";
$svgContent = file_get_contents($imagePath);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($svgContent);
if($xml->xpath("//*[local-name()='use']")) {
    $defsContent = $xml->xpath("//*[local-name()='defs']");
    $defs = []; 
    foreach ($defsContent as $key => $elements) {
        foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
            $defsArray = [];
            $defsArray['id'] = $element['id'];
            $defsArray['content'] = $element;
            array_push($defs, $defsArray);
        }
    }
    
    $usesParent = $xml->xpath("//*[local-name()='use']/..");
    foreach ($usesParent as $key => $parent) {
        $href = ltrim((string)$parent->use->attributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')->href, "#");
        $style = (string)$parent->use->attributes()->style;
        unset($parent->use); 

        foreach ($defs as $key => $def) {
            if($def['id'] == $href) {
                $newElement = $parent->addChild('g');
                $newElement->addAttribute('style', $style);
                $this->simplexml_import_simplexml($newElement, $def['content']);
            }
        }
    }
    // overrides the old svg
    $xml->asXML($imagePath);
}

function simplexml_import_xml($parent, $xml) {
    $xml = (string)$xml;
    if ($nodata = !strlen($xml) or $parent[0] == NULL) {
        return $nodata;
    }
    $node     = dom_import_simplexml($parent);
    $fragment = $node->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML($xml);

    return (bool)$node->appendChild($fragment);
}

function simplexml_import_simplexml($parent, $child) {
    // check if there is something to add
    if ($child[0] == NULL) {
        return true;
    }
    // if it is a list of SimpleXMLElements default to the first one
    $child = $child[0];
    // insert attribute
    if ($child->xpath('.') != array($child)) {
        $parent[$child->getName()] = (string)$child;
        return true;
    }
    $xml = $child->asXML();
    // remove the XML declaration on document elements
    if ($child->xpath('/*') == array($child)) {
        $pos = strpos($xml, "\n");
        $xml = substr($xml, $pos + 1);
    }
    return $this->simplexml_import_xml($parent, $xml);
}
```